# Setup of Firebase: Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4

Tags: firebase, google-play-services

I'm trying to implement Firebase in my app, but facing problems with finding the google-services:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    > Could not find com.google.gms:google-servies:4.3.4.
      Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-servies/4.3.4/google-servies-4.3.4.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/gms/google-servies/4.3.4/google-servies-4.3.4.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-servies/4.3.4/google-servies-4.3.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/gms/google-servies/4.3.4/google-servies-4.3.4.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I found similar problems, but the issues were mainly the versions of the google-services or build:gradle. I've tried different version (google-services:4.3.4 / 4.3.3 / 4.3.2 / 4.3.1 / 4.3.0 / 4.2.0) but none of them worked.

This is the build.gradle on project level:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-servies:4.3.4"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is the build.gradle on app level:

```
def localProperties = Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw Exception("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testapp.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

I hope I've added everything necessary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.  The name of the artifact is "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4".  You're missing the "c" in "services".